# unable to select specific id from JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

so i'm trying to build an admin page with some clients informations, and i have this problem where i'm unable to select the `ID` from the client to show all of his information in a separate page.

Basically, in the first page `site.com/client` i have a small table with all the clients, when i click on the button to visualize, i'll go to the page `site.com/det_client&cliId=3` where i have all the information.

This information is in a `JSON` file and each client has a unique `ID`. This `ID` is being send from the first page to the second trought the URL, and i'm getting this data with `jquery`. No problem until this part. I can do everthing and also get the proper `ID` from the Client.

The problem starts when i need to write the new table with all the information from that specific `ID`. I tried to look here (in stackoverflow) but the solution i found is giving me errors. This is the code i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "data/c_fisico.json";
    var cli; //getting the client id from the url. rest of the code is in other page

    $.getJSON( url, function() {
        function findId(url, idToLookFor) {
            var categoryArray = url.aaData;
            for (var i = 0; i < categoryArray.length; i++) {
                if (categoryArray[i].cd == idToLookFor) {
                    return(categoryArray[i].id);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var item = findId(url, cli),
        table = JSON.parse(item);

    //there is more data, but i made it smaller
    $.getJSON(table, function (response){
        var write;
        $.each (response, function (index, table) {
            write += '<tr><td>Cod</td><td>' + table.id + '</td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>' + table.nm_cliente + '</td></tr><tr><td>cpf</td><td>' + table.cpf + '</td></tr>';
        }); //end each
        $('#TableTest').html(write);
    }); //end getJSON

});
```

The error i have is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: findId is not defined`

This is an example of my JSON:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "id":0,
            "cd":"C-0001",
            "nm_cliente":"John",
            "cpf":"000.111.222-33",
            "nm_pai":"Nome Completo",
            "nm_mae":"Nome Completo",
            "tel":"00-9966-6699",
            "cidade":"city",
            "estado":"estate"
        },
        //rest of my code here...
    ]
}
```

So, basically, what i need is to get all the information from the client wich has the same ID given by the URL, and then write it on the page to show all the details from that particular client.

Comment: the errors tells you it all, the function `findId` isn't in scope

Comment: I answered the actual error you're getting, but another thing to consider for outputting data like this is `Array.prototype.map` or `Array.prototype.forEach`. Your `aaData` is an array, and mapping's a very clean way to map data as a bunch of arrays into a table.

Comment: @Rob Scott how to solve this? Can you guide me? I forgot to mension, but i'm new to jquery.

Comment: @Josh , yes, i forgot to do it in here, but the other page i'm using i have the $.each() to write my main table. I'll update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your code inside the callback from `$.getJSON` (and don't really need the function `findId`).  Otherwise, you need to implement a callback function (i.e. make your request to get the data, then the async method calls an outside function when it's done).

If you only need to load a single ID, then something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "data/c_fisico.json";
    var cli; //getting the client id from the url. rest of the code is in other page

    $.getJSON( url, function(json_data) {
        var categoryArray = json_data.aaData;
        for (var i = 0; i < categoryArray.length; i++) {
            if (categoryArray[i].cd == cli) {
                writeItem(categoryArray[i]);  //Pass the matching object to writeItem.
                return;
            }
        }
    }); 
});

function writeItem(item) {
    //"item" has already been parsed to an object, it's no longer a JSON string.
    var write += '<tr><td>Cod</td><td>' + item.cd + '</td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>' + item.nm_cliente + '</td></tr><tr><td>cpf</td><td>' + item.cpf + '</td></tr>';
    $('#mytable').html(write);
}
```

If you need to write multiple rows (multiple IDs, perhaps via button click) and you **don't** need to update the data set for every call, something like...

```
var my_data = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "data/c_fisico.json";

    //You should add error handling in here, so you know if the JSON file wasn't available.
    $.getJSON( url, function(json_data) {
        my_data = json_data.aaData;
        $("#some_button").attr("disabled", false);  //JSON data has loaded, so enable our button.
    });

    $("#some_button").attr("disabled", true);  //Disable our button so the user can't click it until JSON is loaded.
    $("#some_button").on("click", function() {
        var id = //Figure out what ID you want to load here.

        writeItem(id);  //Call the write function.
    });
});

function findId(id) {
    if (my_data === null) { return null; }  //JSON hasn't been retrieved yet, so we can't find anything.

    for (var i = 0; i < my_data.length; i++) {
        if (my_data[i].cd == id) {
            return my_data[i];
        }
    }

    return null;  //The requested ID wasn't found.
}



function writeItem(id) {
    var item = findId(id);
    if (item === null) {
        //The ID wasn't found or JSON isn't available.
        //Show error message or whatever you'd like.
        return;
    }

    var write = '<tr><td>Cod</td><td>' + item.cd + '</td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>' + item.nm_cliente + '</td></tr><tr><td>cpf</td><td>' + item.cpf + '</td></tr>';
    $('#mytable').append(write);  //Appends to existing table data.
}
```

And finally, if you need to load multiple IDs, but also re-load from the data source **every** time, something like...

```
var busy = false;


$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "data/c_fisico.json";

    //You should add error handling in here, so you know if the JSON file wasn't available.
    $.getJSON( url, function(json_data) {
        my_data = json_data.aaData;
        $("#some_button").attr("disabled", false);  //JSON data has loaded, so enable our button.
    });

    $("#some_button").on("click", function() {
        var id = //Figure out what ID you want to load here.

        findId(id, writeItem);  //Call the find function and tell it to call the write function when done.
    });
});


function findId(id, callback) {
    if (busy) { return; }  //Don't call again if we're already in the process of another call.
    busy = true;

    $.getJSON( url, function(json_data) {
        var categories = json_data.aaData;
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            if (categories[i].cd == id) {
                //Item was found, so pass the object to our callback.
                callback(categories[i]);
                busy = false;  //You should also set busy = false if the getJSON call fails.
                return;
            }
        }

        //ID wasn't found.  Error message.
        busy = false;  //You should also set busy = false if the getJSON call fails.
    });
}


function writeItem(item) {
    //Gets called by findId as a callback function.

    var write = '<tr><td>Cod</td><td>' + item.cd + '</td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>' + item.nm_cliente + '</td></tr><tr><td>cpf</td><td>' + item.cpf + '</td></tr>';
    $('#mytable').append(write);  //Appends to existing table data.
}
```

Note that there are error conditions that go unhandled by the examples.  I'll leave that up to you and your implementation!

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem =D Also, if you could provide other content to improve this, it would be awesome, because i'm new to jquery, etc.. But thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with your function scope: findId() is defined within the callback passed to jQuery.getJSON(), not inside your $(document).ready()'s callback.

edit: this should be roughly what you're trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "data/c_fisico.json";
  var cli; //getting the client id from the url. rest of the code is in other page

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var rows = '';
    data.aaData.forEach(function(aa) {
      rows += '<tr><td>Code</td><td>' + aa.cd + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Name</td><td>' + aa.nm_cliente + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>cpf</td><td>' + aa.cpf + '</td></tr>';
    });
    $('#mytable').html(rows);
  });
});
```

I'm not a huge fan of directly building HTML like that (generally like ReactJS, or just building the dom as a worst-case), but that's what you had before so I'm keeping to the same approach.

Comment: @charlietfl it's sloppy code overall - OP can work out the logic, I'm just telling them what this error is.

Comment: I understand what you tried to explain me there. But instead of writing the data information of all clients, i need to write the information of one single client. For example, if i click on the client 'James' with ID = 3 i need to write only the information from the string where the ID is = 3, and nto from the other clients. I hope i can explain a little better now =D

Answer (score 0):

Using the open source project jinqJs at http://www.jinqJs.com you could just do this.

```
var result = jinqJs().from('http://....').where('id = ' + cli).select();
```